# Host key verification failed occurred while deploying Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

#### Problem

When I try to deploy cloud functions, sometimes `Host key verification failed.` is occurred.
It seems to be occurred in GCP, because I can be done `npm install` on my local.

#### Circumstance

When I replace my ssh key then it seems to be ok for a while, but it will reproduce.

I use gitlab to manage source code and some common repository is in gitlab.
The project which is tried to deploy function has dependency for this common repository.

#### Environment

node v10.17.0
npm v6.11.3
firebase v7.12.1

#### Error log

```
⚠  functions[appv1(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: {"error":{"buildpackId":"google.nodejs.npm","buildpackVersion":"0.9.0","errorType":2,"canonicalCode":2,"errorId":"b0ba1f57","errorMessage":"npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142\nnpm WARN deprecated sendgrid@1.9.2: Please see v6.X+ at https://www.npmjs.com/org/sendgrid\nnpm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@\u003c3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.\nnpm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.\nnpm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated\nnpm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated\nnpm ERR! Error while executing:\nnpm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@gitlab.com/myrepos/my-rpc-client.git\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Host key verification failed.\nnpm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights\nnpm ERR! and the repository exists.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! exited with error code: 128\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T02_36_20_019Z-debug.log"},"stats":null}
```

#### Code

Here is a snippet of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --cache",
    "build": "tsc",
    "buildWatch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "jest --coverage --verbose"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.7.3",
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^5.5.5",
    "my-rpc-client": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/myrepos/my-rpc-client.git#1.0.0",
  },
  "private": true
}
```

#### Additional Information

I have found some articles and tried to set "ignore" option to "package-lock.json" and also tried to use node v8, but it is not working.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/446
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/607

Does anybody have solution??

Comment: This seems to be related with GitLab connection.  What type of key are you using?

Comment: For your common repository, you can create a tarball (host keys will not be required), it's working for us on node 10.19.0 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/968#issuecomment-460323113

Additionally, if you have a typed package from your repo/monorepo as a devDependency remove that from Cloud functions package.json>devDependency before deployment. This will work because the typings aren't required during the running of the JS code.

Comment: @vitooh I created ssh key by ed25519.